# OSX messed up PATH

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, path

I was trying to make `Sublime` editor work from Terminal following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/1195304) and by doing so I modified the `.bash_profile` file and apparently my PATH. While I was doing this I was positioned in some random folder in Terminal, it was `/Users/apple/Desktop/RailsCode/readit/` and now if I want to run command `open ~./bash_profile` it says: `The file /Users/apple/Desktop/RailsCode/readit/~./bash_profile does not exist.` And it worked before, it seems to me I messed up my default PATH. How to resolve this?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: are you maybe confusing `~./bash_profile` (a directory named "bash_profile" which doesn't exist) and `~/.bash_profile` (a file in your root folder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is not quite right:

```
open ~./bash_profile
      ^
```

should be:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
       ^
```

Comment: exactly, it was a typo... thanks

Comment: How is this question a dup...?

Comment: @Thomas: I didn't actually flag it as a dupe (I flagged it as belonging on superuser.com, since it's not a programming question), but I guess someone else used their dupehammer.